# Let $\mathbb{K} $ be a field of characteristic $p>0$ and $\mathbb{F} | \mathbb{K} $ a finite and separable extension.

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$ and $\mathbb{F}/ \mathbb{K}$ a finite and separable extension. Show that if $B=\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ is a basis, then $C=\{\alpha_1^p,\dots,\alpha_n^p\}$ is a basis.

Well, my first idea is to use the following map:

$T:\mathbb{F}\longrightarrow\mathbb{F}$ where $T(\alpha_i)=\alpha_i^p$ with $i=1,\dots,n$

Proving that $T$ is isomorphism between vector spaces the problem is solved, since that $T$ carries basis to basis.

$T(k\alpha_i)=kT(\alpha_i)$ for $k\in\mathbb{K}$.

Now i have to prove $T(\alpha_i+\alpha_j)=\alpha_i^p + \alpha_j^p$, surjectivity and injectivity of $T$, but at first, it does not look true.

Maybe I'm in the wrong way, because I'm not using the fact that $\mathbb{F}/\mathbb{K}$ is separable.

Comment: The statement that $T$ is surjective is equivalent to what you want to prove, because it implies that $\{\alpha_1^p,\dots,\alpha_n^p\}$ is a spanning set for $\mathbb{F}$ over $\mathbb{K}$. Note that defining $T$ on a basis gives you automatically a linear map, so you don't need to prove linearity.

Comment: @egreg why is it automatically linear?

Comment: You have prescribed the action of $T$ on a basis, not defined it on all elements of $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: @egreg:  I understand your correct issues with my (temporarily, I hope) deleted post;  too early;  pre-coffee MSE is probably not the best idea for me! ;-)  Anyway, let me see if I can patch that one up!  Cheers!

Comment: @egreg You are saying that even if T is not linear, it carries basis to basis? I can not give a counterexample, but in all books of linear algebra this hypothesis is needed and in the middle of demonstration the fact that T(a + b) =  T(a) + T(b) is used.

Comment: if $T$ is surjective, let $y=T(\sum a_i \alpha_i)$.  Then $y=\sum a_i \alpha_i^p$ by $\mathbb{K}$ linearity of $T$.  Since arbitrary $y$ can be written as an $\mathbb{K}$ linear combination of $\alpha_i^p$, that shows $\alpha_i^p$ is a spanning set, and therefore a basis.  The point is you're defining $T$ by $\mathbb{K}$ linearity, and $\mathbb{F}$ is finite of $\mathbb{K}$, so showing surjectivity would show $T$ is a vector space isomorphism.

Comment: @egreg:  well, I guess this problem is harder than I first guessed!:-) I guess "tempororily" will be longer than I first expected!  Something to keep the neurons firing for awhile, it apoears.  Cheers!

Comment: **Hint:** It is enough to check that the $n$ elements $\alpha_1^p, \alpha_2^p, \ldots, \alpha_n^p$ span $\mathbb{F}$ over $\mathbb{K}$. Show first that the $\mathbb{K}$-linear span of these elements is an $\mathbb{F}$-subalgebra of $\mathbb{K}$. Argue that, being an integral domain, it thus is a subfield (use the fact that an injective endomorphism of a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector space is always surjective), and $\mathbb{K}$ is purely inseparable over it. Prove that if $A / B / C$ is a finite field extension with $A / C$ separable and $A / B$ purely inseparable, then $A = B$.